# Tricky concatenation of header names with column values and pivot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to combine the column name with each column value and display the label count.

```
For example, for id 'aa' in 2022 Q1, there is 1 'hi'  
             for id 'aa' in 2022 Q2, there are 2 'hi' 's
```

**Data**

```
id  type    date    Q1  Q2
aa  hi      2022    1   2
aa  hi      2023    1   1
aa  ok      2022    1   0
bb  hi      2024    3   0
```

**Desired**

```
id  type    date        count
aa  hi      Q1 2022     hi01
aa  ok      Q1 2022     ok01
aa  hi      Q2 2022     hi01
aa  hi      Q2 2022     hi02
aa  hi      Q1 2023     hi01
aa  hi      Q2 2023     hi01
bb  hi      Q1 2024     hi01
bb  hi      Q1 2024     hi02
bb  hi      Q1 2024     hi03
```

**Doing**

My approach is to break this apart in steps.
I believe I have to perform a pivot, join and a cumcount:

**#create a pivot**

```
df.set_index(['id', 'type']).stack().reset_index()
```

**#set the count**

```
 df['count'] = df['type'] + df.groupby([*df]).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
(df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'type', 'date'], value_name='count') # reshape data
   .sort_values(by=['date', 'variable'])
   # duplicate the rows according to counts
   .loc[lambda d: d.index.repeat(d['count'])]
   .reset_index(drop=True)
           # merge the quarters and years
   .assign(date=lambda d: d['variable']+' '+d['date'].astype(str),
           # increment the type per group
           count=lambda d: d['type']+d.groupby(['id', 'date', 'type']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
          )
   # drop now unused column
   .drop(columns='variable')
)
```

output:

```
   id type     date count
0  aa   hi  Q1 2022  hi01
1  aa   ok  Q1 2022  ok01
2  aa   hi  Q2 2022  hi01
3  aa   hi  Q2 2022  hi02
4  aa   hi  Q1 2023  hi01
5  aa   hi  Q2 2023  hi01
6  bb   hi  Q1 2024  hi01
7  bb   hi  Q1 2024  hi02
8  bb   hi  Q1 2024  hi03
```

Comment: Hi @mozway thanks - just wondering, why the entire statement needs parentheses around them? couldn't it start as  df.melt without ()?

Comment: This is to chain the commands, you could also write everything line by line: `df2 = df.melt(…) ; df2 = df2.sort_values(…) ; df2 = df2.loc[…]` etc.

Comment: @Lynn if you don't mind me asking, what kind of line of work are you in? I often see your questions and it made be curious about the use cases ;)

Comment: Working with different data transformations for academic study projects